# flutter hook useContext example

Tags: flutter, flutter-hooks

Is there any example of useContext() function example?
I want to use

```
AppLocalizations.of(context).someText
```

in many of hook widgets and I am not sure if it is just enough to wrap it in useEffect function on initialize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use like this.

```
Widget _getAccountRegister() {
    final context = useContext();
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: FlatButton(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        onPressed: () {
          NavigationUtils.push(context, routeRegister);
        },
        child: Text(Localization.of(context).signIn),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: It throws error => Failed assertion: line 609 pos 5: 'HookElement._currentHookElement != null': `useContext` can only be called from the build method of HookWidget.

Comment: `useContext` is used only in the build method. I have called the above method `_getAccountRegister()` in the build method of the widget which is extended by HookWidget.

Answer (score 0):

I used `useContext()` in my cubit helper function. It's global, but used inside of `build()` methods in `HookWidgets`:

```
void useCubitListener<BLOC extends Cubit<S>, S>(
  BLOC bloc,
  BlocListener<BLOC, S> listener, {
  bool Function(S current)? listenWhen,
}) {
 final context = useContext();
 final listenWhenConditioner = listenWhen;
 useMemoized(
() {
  final stream =
      bloc.stream.where(listenWhenConditioner ?? (state) => true).listen((state) => listener(bloc, state, context));
  return stream.cancel;
},
[bloc],
  );
}
```

and then:

```
useCubitListener<BookDetailsCubit, BookDetailsPageState>(cubit, (cubit, state, context) {
  state.maybeWhen(
    saveBook: () => context.router.pop<bool>(true),
    deleteBook: () => context.router.pop<bool>(true),
    orElse: () => null,
  );
}, listenWhen: (state) => (state is BookDetailsPageSaveBook));
```

More on cubits and hooks [here](https://medium.com/@tonia.tkachuk/flutter-list-details-app-with-cubits-hooks-and-hive-database-2e87be09b580).